# How do we prove that cancellation law is hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Suppose i have

$$2x+8=3$$

I believe the first think that comes out from your mind is adding $(-3)$ on both sides.

Suppose we don't know about cancellation law. How do you prove that when we adding the same number on both side **won't change the equality?**

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind isn‘t adding $(-3)$ on both sides.

Comment: Then what? What i'm asking here is, why we add the same thing on both side. Is there a theorem or axiom before we know the cancellation law?

Comment: Are you doubting whether $a=b$ implies $a+c=b+c$?

Comment: Yes, I can see, it‘s a good question. I believe this depends on the definition of the equal sign - which is probably rigorously done in ZFC with the axiom of extensionality. Hopefully, an expert in set theory/logic will be able to help, though.

Comment: I'm not doubting anything. Ok forget about the cancellation. Suppose i want to add the same thing on both side. **How do i proce that it won't change the equality?**. And in this case suppose it not use the cancellation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I believe the question should rather more be about the foundations of the equal sign, so ultimately the definition/axioms of $=$ which imo is a good “doubt”/curiosity.

Comment: Also related: [Is there a low that you can add or multiply to both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100564/is-there-a-law-that-you-can-add-or-multiply-to-both-sides-of-an-equation?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link... and i've read all of those. But i don't think that my question is answered from those. Cz i need the proof of it. Not the intuition about why do this makes sense. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Binary operations are well-defined functions.

Note that $$x=a \iff x+b=a+b$$ and if $a\ne 0$, the $$ax=b \iff x=b/a$$

The reason is that addition, subtraction, multiplication and division by a non-zero element are  well-defined functions.

For example if I have $x=a$, since adding $b$ is a function, we get $x+b=a+b$ that is if inputs are the same then outputs are the same.