# How do we algebraically manipulate non-commutative equations? (Ie. Diagonalization: $A=PDP^{-1} \rightarrow AP=PD$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

1. How can we manipulate non-commutative equations? (See question 3 below)
2. It seems in the formula for Diagonalization, $A=PDP^{-1} \rightarrow AP=PD$, does one just multiply both sides by P?
3. Main question: How do we manipulate it instead to $PAP^{-1}=D$?

Comment: For the second question, the answer is that we multiply both sides by $P$ from the right, since order matters. Apart from this, the post is very difficult to decipher. I'm not sure at all what you're actually wondering about; matrix multiplication is associative but not commutative, but it seems like you already know this...

Comment: Thanks @Scounged I've edited the qn based on your feedback and reworded qn 1 & 3. The question is, how do we algebraically manipulate non-commutative equations?

Comment: FWIW I think this question was actually better in its original form (and it's when it was in that form that I responded to it).

Comment: Thanks Noah, I think I need to figure out how to get to qn 3 and I'd be able to clarify what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not the *equation* that is non-commutative, but rather the *operation used in* the equation.

As to the main point, there's actually nothing special here, we just have to be a bit more careful. The basic logical apparatus of equality (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679761/which-field-property-enables-us-to-multiply-on-both-sides-by-the-same-value-whi/3679842#3679842) for more on this) tells us that given any well-defined function $F$ and any true equation $s=t$, the equation $F(s)=F(t)$ is again a true equation. In particular, this applies to $F(x)=xy$ for a fixed $y$, as well as to $G(x)=yx$ for a fixed $y$. The non-commutativity of multiplication in our current setting means that $F$ and $G$ are not the same in general, but that's fine.

So, looking at your particular example, we argue as follows:

- We start with $A=PDP^{-1}$ by assumption.
- We now apply the principle above with $F(x)=xP$. This gives $$F(A)=F(PDP^{-1})\quad\implies \quad AP=PDP^{-1}P\quad\implies AP=PD.$$

Now we **are** still being a bit informal - we're being rather cavalier with respect to the **associative** property of multiplication (which still holds). Ultimately a fully formal approach will involve some parentheses-juggling. But the above is perfectly adequate for the topic.

Note that we didn't simply "multiply by $P$" - in the absence of commutativity, "multiplication by $P$" isn't well-defined. Our $F$ in this case was multiplication *on the right* by $P$. We could also have multiplied by $P$ on the *left* on both sides of the equation, getting $$PA=P^2DP^{-1}.$$ However, we *could not* multiply by $P$ on the left in the left hand side and on the right on the right hand side: $PA=PD$ is not something we can conclude from $A=PDP^{-1}$ (without further hypotheses, at least).

Comment: Hi @noah schweber, thanks for your reply, it really helpful to think of them as functions rather than algebra. So are you saying in point 3: I'd have to define the function F as "multiply by P, on the left hand side": $F=P$(on left hand side), then apply the functions to both sides like so $F(AP^{-1})=F(PD)$, in order to get $PAP^{-1}=D$?